# Managing of Navier-Stokes PDEs by means of SBF in Dymola

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Has anyone tried to implement the Navier Stokes Partial Differential Equations (PDE) in Modelica?
I found the method of the spatial basis functions (SBF) which by means of numerical modifications gets Ordinary Differential Equations (ODE) that could be handled by Dymola.

Regards,

Victor

Answer (score 2):

The aim of the method I was saying before is to convert PDEs in ODEs, so the issues with the CFL coefficient would disappear, the problem is that the Modelica.Fluids elements just define the equations in function of the variables in both ends of each component.

i.e `dp=port_a.p-port_b.p`

but with that sort of methodology, the variables such as pressure, density, mass flow... would be function also of the surrounding components... it would be a kind of massive interaction between all the components,

I would like to see an example in Modelica, because I hardly haven't found information about that topic linked to Modelica.

Answer (score 1):

Modelica is a language for modeling behavior described by DAEs.  As such, as long as you can create a system of ODEs, you should be able to express your problem in Modelica.

However, if your PDEs are hyperbolic, the wave dynamics in the equations might cause some issues with simulation.  This is because the [CFL condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition) imposes limits on time steps that an ordinary differential equation solver will be unaware of.  If the solver includes error control, it will probably manage to get a solutions but may run quite slow because it won't know how to explicitly limit the simulation step size.  If it doesn't include error control and it violates the CFL condition, the system will go unstable.  Note, this only applies to systems where the CFL condition applies.